# Ajax stopped working after executing a query

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to load comments from a php file using ajax.

index.php

```
<div id="commentsonpost" value="<?php echo $_GET['post'];?>">
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var postid = $('#commentsonpost').attr("value");
    alert(postid);
    var dataString = 'getpostcomm=1&postid='+ postid;
    $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "getcomments.php",
                data: dataString,
                dataType:'html',
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                        alert("re");
                     $("#commentsonpost").append(html);


          }
         });

    return false;
});
</script>
```

getcomments.php

```
if(isset($_GET['getpostcomm'])){


$var=$_GET['postid']; //  Adding this line causing problems

$querycomm = "select U.fname,U.lname,U.usernick,C.bcommentid,C.comment,C.date,C.visible from blogcomments as C natural join users as U where C.visible=1 and U.visible=1 and C.bpostid='{$var}' ORDER BY C.date ASC";

$resultcomm = mysql_query ( $querycomm, $connection );
echo "<div id='pcomments'>";
while($commentonpost=mysql_fetch_array($resultcomm)){
    if($commentonpost['visible']==1){
        echo '
        <div style="width:90%;float:left;margin-left:5%;margin-right:15%;margin-top:10px;" id="comment'.$commentonpost['commentid'].'">

        <div style="width:10%;float:left;"><a href="profile.php?user='.$commentonpost['usernick'].'"  >'.$commentonpost['fname']." ".$commentonpost['lname'].'</a></div>
        <div style="width:78%;float:left;margin-left:2%;">'.$commentonpost['comment'].'</div>
        <div style="width:8%;float:right;margin-left:2%;">
        ';
        if($commentonpost['usernick']==$_SESSION['user_nick']){
            echo '  <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="submit"  name="delcomm" value="X" class="delcombutton" id="'.$commentonpost['commentid'].'">

            </form>
            ';
        }
        echo '<h5 class="msg">'.datetime($commentonpost['date']).'</h5>
        </div>
        <br/>
        </div>

        ';
    }
}
echo "</div>";




echo '
<form name = "form" method = "post" action=""  onsubmit="return validateform()" style="width:100%">
<div style="width:90%;float:left;margin-left:5%;margin-right:15%;margin-top:10px;">

<div style="width:10%;float:left;"><a href="profile.php?user='.$_SESSION['user_nick'].'"  >'.$_SESSION['user_fname']." ".$_SESSION['user_lname'].'</a></div>
<div style="width:78%;float:left;margin-left:2%;"><textarea placeholder="Comment..." name="commenttext" id="commenttext" class="inputcomment" ></textarea></div>

<br>
<input type="submit" id="'.$_POST['post'].'" name="SubmitComment" value="Comment " class="commentbutton" style="font-size:1em;width:100px;float:right;margin-top:4px;margin-right:9%;">
</div>
</form>
</div>
';

}
```

Whenever i add that  `$var=$_GET['postid'];` line in getcomments.php ajax script stop working. As soon as i remove `$var=$_GET['postid'];` from getcomments.php, excluding query part(obviously) form is displaying correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Stopped working" is not exactly a helpful description... What does that mean? Anythin in the browsers console? Any errors in the http servers log? What payload is sent from and to the server?

Comment: `$_GET['postid'];` this line is causing problem because you have defined the variable **postid** wrong way in ajax call. change the ajax call data option from `data: dataString,` to `data:{pID: dataString},`.

Comment: What happens if you just go to `getcomments.php?getpostcomm=1&postid=X`. Are you getting php errors ?

Comment: **postid** is defined outside your ajax call,and the value passed in ajax call is **datastring**. so this behaviour was intended

Comment: Side note: your code is wide open to sql injections. You have to check what content `$_GET['postid']` actually contains and you should stop using the old, depreciated mysql extension. Switch to PDO or the newer mysqli extension instead and use prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you all for replying,After applying all suggested updates, on this page `getcomments.php?getpostcomm=1&postid=1` i am getting all my comments on that post, but not form! @ark, yes, this is just a testing area.

Answer (score 0):

At ajax better set data fields as array values as:

```
$.ajax({
type: "get",
url: "getcomments.php",
data: {'getpostcomm':1,'postid':postid},
```

And at your PHP you have to sanitize your Id.. (if its int you may at least cast (int) )...

```
$var = (int) $_GET['postid'];
```

Also at your PHP add check if isset($_GET['postid'])...

```
if(isset($_GET['getpostcomm']) && isset($_GET['postid'])){
```

Comment: Now thats what i call the perfect way of making ajax call

Comment: That doesn't makes any changes. Actually whole thing is triggered by, `$var=(int)$_GET['getpostcomm'];` as soon as i add this i get no response from getcomments.php `(alert("re"); wont work too)` but `getcomments.php?getpostcomm=1&postid=1` is showing all comments w/o form. But when i remove `$var=(int)$_GET['getpostcomm'];` i get response from  getcomments.php `(alert("re"); works too)` but `getcomments.php?getpostcomm=1&postid=1` is showing form only.

Comment: Add mysql_error to see whats wrong...
mysql_query() or die(mysql_error());

Comment: No query execution is fine, i tried adding `print_r($commentonpost)` inside the while loop and everything works! But adding that div thing  inside while loop is matter now. PS:  i changed `$commentonpost['comment'] => $commentonpost['bcomment'] `

Comment: Do you have any server error log to check for any PHP errors ?

Comment: Yup while loop is terminating after one loop, but array contain many elements!

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataString = 'getpostcomm=1&postid='+ toString(postid);
```